# Adjust diffplot to show histogram on the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been realizing http://labrtorian.com/tag/difference-plot/ (the data itself is probably not necessary so I stick only to the plotting line):

```
diffplot <- ggplot(my.data, aes(baseline, diff)) + 
  geom_point(size=2, colour = rgb(0,0,0, alpha = 0.5)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  #when the +/- 2SD lines will fall outside the default plot limits 
  #they need to be pre-stated explicitly to make the histogram line up properly. 
  #Thanks to commenter for noticing this.
  ylim(mean(my.data$diff) - 3*sd.diff, mean(my.data$diff) + 3*sd.diff) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(my.data$diff)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(my.data$diff) + 2*sd.diff, linetype = 2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(my.data$diff) - 2*sd.diff, linetype = 2) +
  ylab("Difference pre and post Storage (mg/L)") +
  xlab("Baseline Concentration (mg/L)")

#And now for the magic - we'll use 25 bins
ggMarginal(diffplot, type="histogram", bins = 25)
```

and I have the problem that when I plot it like that I get

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 11 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin). 
3: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

This is solvable when changing       `ylim(mean(my.data$diff) - 3*sd.diff, mean(my.data$diff) + 3*sd.diff)` to (in my case)      `ylim(mean(my.data$diff) - 2000*sd.diff, mean(my.data$diff) + 2000*sd.diff)` so obviously the range plays the role.
Problem is now: When I adjust the range then the plot is nearly senseless because you can hardly see anything. When I stick with the regular ranges as above then it's fine except for the histogram on y at the right side:

[image: Plot]

Plot without warnings:

[image: Plot2]

The author resp. a commenter also faced that and described what to do in such a case. Unfortunately I don't understand it:

> when the +/- 2SD lines will fall outside the default plot limits
>   they need to be pre-stated explicitly to make the histogram line up properly.

How do I state the data points explicitly which cause the range problem? Or in other words: What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will get problems with ggmargin using the ylim() argument. Therefore you will have to pre-state the upper- and lower- margin explicitly. In your case:  delete the  ylim lines

```
  ylim(mean(my.data$diff) - 3*sd.diff, mean(my.data$diff) + 3*sd.diff) +
```

and keep the pre-stated lines

```
 geom_hline(yintercept = mean(my.data$diff) + 3*sd.diff, linetype = 2) +
 geom_hline(yintercept = mean(my.data$diff) - 3*sd.diff, linetype = 2) +
```